# Filtering on the basis of tags in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have an array of tags as a model field, I want to filter out based on those array elements. here is the model in which tag field is an array type I guess.

```
class Mineral(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tags=TaggableManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now in my view, I want to filter out based on this tag field
I can do that using Django way like this

```
class MineralList(APIView):
    queryset = Mineral.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MineralSerializer

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        mineral = Mineral.objects.all()

        tags = request.query_params.get('tags', None)
        name= request.query_params.get('name',None)

        if tags is not None:
            tags = tags.split(',')
            mineral = mineral.filter(tags__name__in=tags).distinct()
        if name:
            mineral = mineral.filter(name=name)
        serializer = MineralSerializer(mineral, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I do that in REST way using filter backends and Filter class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the FilterSet class like this:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, filters
from django_filters.widgets import CSVWidget


class MineralFilterSet(FilterSet):
    tags = filters.CharFilter(distinct=True, widget=CSVWidget, method='filter_tags')
    name = filters.CharFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Mineral
        fields = ['name', 'tags']

    def filter_tags(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=value)
```

And your view should be like this:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class MineralList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Mineral.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MineralSerializer

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MineralFilterSet
```

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting Gabriel's answer to work, so in case anyone else is facing this issue here is what worked for me.

Filter:

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, filters
from django_filters.widgets import CSVWidget

from .models import Contact


class ContactFilter(FilterSet):
    tags = filters.BaseCSVFilter(
        distinct=True, widget=CSVWidget(), method="filter_tags"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        
    @staticmethod
    def filter_tags(queryset, field_name, value):
        return queryset.filter(tags__name__in=value)
```

ViewSet:

```py
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ContactViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ContactFilter
```

The important part is to use BaseCSVFilter instead of CharFilter, otherwise the CSVWidget will spit out a string of the list, instead of a list.